# Ifstream experiencing creating random exceptions

Tags: c++, file, io, ifstream

I am trying to read some data from a .txt file using an ifstream so I can pass it into values of a class I created. This function is inside of a class, so the integers aren't declared at the top of the funciton. The ifstream works for the first few values I read in, but it throws exceptions randomly, (i have no idea why) on one of the lines. Every once in a while( it seems like 1 in 50) the stream will work with no errors.

I've tried changing the format of the input file. If I put a line at the top of the file, (and then read in a test number), it fixes my issue. For this program, however, I cant change the format of my input file.

```
int parameters::readParameters() {

ifstream in_stream;
string paramFile = "data/Parameter.txt";
string label;
string option;

// read in file
in_stream.open(paramFile);

// file isn't opened
if (in_stream.fail()) {
    cerr << "\nFailed opening Parameter.txt\n";
    return 1;
}

// read non data line
in_stream >> label;

// figure out objective
int optionPicker = 0;
int numOptions = 4;
for (int i = 1; i <= numOptions; i++) {
    in_stream >> label >> option;
    if (option == "Y") optionPicker = i;

}
if (optionPicker == 1) obj = minAvgBid;
else if (optionPicker == 2) obj = maxFirstBid;
else if (optionPicker == 3) obj = maxFithOrBettterBid;
else if (optionPicker == 4) obj = maxNumFivePerTeam;
else obj = none;


// read non data line
in_stream >> label;

/*

The Error occurs directly after this comment

*/

// read upper bounds
in_stream >> label >> maxNumProj;
in_stream >> label >> worstRanking;

// read non data line
in_stream >> label;

// read lower bounds
in_stream >> label >> minNumFiveTeam;
in_stream >> label >> minNumFirstBid;
in_stream >> label >> minNumFifthBid;

// read non data line
in_stream >> label;

// read english options
int english;
in_stream >> label >> english;
if (english == 1) engOpt = option1;
else if (english == 2) engOpt = option2;
else if (english == 3) engOpt = option3;
else if (english == 4) engOpt = option4;

// read native english
string nativeEng;
in_stream >> label >> nativeEng;
if (nativeEng == "Y") native = choice1;
else native = choice2;

// read non data line
in_stream >> label;

// read solution number
in_stream >> label >> solNum;

//if (checkParameters() == 1) return 1;

in_stream.close();

cout << "Parameters Read!" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

-----------------------------Input File ----------------------------

```
Choose_ONE_objective:
Min_avg_bid Y
Max_first_bid N
Max_fifth_bid N
Max_five_teams N
Choose_Upper_Bounds:
UB_num_proj 60
UB_bid 10
Choose_Lower_Bounds:
LB_5_teams 0                       <- the error occurs on this line
LB_first_bid 0
LB_fifth_bid 0
Choose_English_Option:
English_Option 2
Native_English_Lowest Y
Select_Output_Label:
Solution_Number 20
```

An exception is thrown: Access violation reading at 0x000....

Comment: On what line does the access violation happens?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't indicate that. I'll edit the code

Comment: What type is `maxNumProj`?

Comment: You haven't given us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and I can't reproduce the error with the code you've posted. What happens if you remove the code that reads past that line?

Comment: Does istream have the operator >> for strings?

Comment: @MartinVéronneau Yes. Please see the [reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt).

Comment: `in_stream >> label;` does not read a complete line and leaves `'\n'` in the input stream unread. Validating each read, e.g. `if (!(in_stream >> label)) { /* handle error */ }` will catch and protect against continuing attempted reads from a stream in an error state. You can also check `in_stream.bad()`, or `in_stream.fail()` or `in_stream.eof()` to determine the failure.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I was under the impression that for istreams, the [<< operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) was overloaded for basic types, but reading in strings required the use of `getline`.